# OrderItem Creation via Enterprise wsdl call

Tags: api, order, enterprise-wsdl, orderitem

I am trying to create via Enterprise WSDL create call an `OrderItem` record related to an order.

As per image below, inside my call i pass the `OrderID`, the `PriceBook ID`, `Quantity` and `Line Description`, but I am not able to add the Product ID (or Product2 identifier) since the field is missing inside the wsdl definition. 
I want to highlight also that the order item object has Product2 field inside object definition.

Could you please help me with this API call ? How can i add the product id to the orderItem creation call ?

I also tryied to add manually  field inside the request, but when i try to execute it, i get the following error:

> "Invalid foreign key relationship name Product2"

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled; For OrderItem, you always supply the `PriceBookEntryId` and never the Product2Id - `Product2Id` is not a field on `OrderItem`. Is it possible you haven't enabled Pricebooks or given access to Products to the running user?

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the enterprise wsdl again, after you added that field? Enterprise wsdl requires a download again after any changes to the object model.

Comment: Hi Shalini, the Enterprise wsdl is updated. However I have not added any field to objects.